# Disable Scaffold FAB animation

Tags: flutter

By default, the Scaffold in Flutter animates the floating action button (FAB) when changing a FAB while the app is running.

[image: scaling animation]

How can I disable this animation?

The [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/floatingActionButtonAnimator.html) references the `FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling` animation which scales the button when it changes:

> /// Animator to move the [floatingActionButton] to a new
>   [floatingActionButtonLocation].   ///   /// If null, the
>   [ScaffoldState] will use the default animator,
>   [FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling].   final
>   FloatingActionButtonAnimator floatingActionButtonAnimator;

However, there is no indication on how to disable the scaling animation completely.

Full example code with the issue:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Timer _timer;
  bool showFirst = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        showFirst = !showFirst;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: showFirst
          ? FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked
          : FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Floating Action Button Title'),
            showFirst
                ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    heroTag: 'unique',
                    icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
                    label: Text('First FAB'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                : FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    heroTag: 'unique2',
                    icon: Icon(Icons.filter_2),
                    label: Text('Second FAB'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Adding a different hero tag to each FAB doesn't affect the animation.

Comment: If you read the [FloatingActionButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) docs. You'll see that its heroTag parameter has a default value of const _DefaultHeroTag(). You can try to change this to disable the Hero Animation.

Comment: It is still using the scaling animation (floatingActionButtonAnimator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to extend FloatingActionButtonAnimator and override its methods, check the following code,

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Timer _timer;
  bool showFirst = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        showFirst = !showFirst;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: NoScalingAnimation(),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: showFirst
          ? FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked
          : FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Floating Action Button Title'),
            showFirst
                ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: 'unique',
              icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
              label: Text('First FAB'),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
                : FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: 'unique2',
              icon: Icon(Icons.filter_2),
              label: Text('Second FAB'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class NoScalingAnimation extends FloatingActionButtonAnimator{
  double _x;
  double _y;
  @override
  Offset getOffset({Offset begin, Offset end, double progress}) {
  _x = begin.dx +(end.dx - begin.dx)*progress;
  _y = begin.dy +(end.dy - begin.dy)*progress;
    return Offset(_x,_y);
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getRotationAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent);
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getScaleAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent);
  }
}
```

[image]

You can control the animation behavior by changing what every method returns. for ex. you can make the fab jump from left to right without animation, by changing `getOffset` method to be

```
  @override
  Offset getOffset({Offset begin, Offset end, double progress}) {
    if (progress == 1.0){
      return end;
    }else{
      return begin;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop it shifting left to right as well?

Comment: you can implement any behavior you want by controlling the three methods, check the added portion to the answer.

Comment: what about changing duration of the movement(slowly shifting)? @SaedNabil

Comment: @KhamidjonKhamidov you can not control this duration as per design the duration is constant `const Duration kFloatingActionButtonSegue = Duration(milliseconds: 200)'

Comment: ok. Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

floatingActionButtons in Flutter have property named heroTag, and every floatingActionButtons have the same default value for it. Giving each floatingActionButtons unique heroTag will prevent the animation from happening.

```
Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: "somethingUnique",
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Icon(Icons.add,),
    ),
    body: Container(),
)
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, added a full code demo as an example

Comment: why inside of a column?

Comment: you can use `heroTag: null` as well.

Answer (score 0):

found this issue thread on flutter official repo

a workaround is to use `Stack` and `Positioned` Widgets (in the Scaffold body argument)

please refer to the code [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61099#issuecomment-2009105139)