# Cannot disable appearance animations on a "floatingActionButton" widget

Tags: flutter, animation, floating-action-button, scaffold

The floatingActionButton property of Scaffold accepts any widget, so I use there a row of a few custom containers to take advantage of the floating effect. I've set the floatingActionButtonLocation property to "centerFloat". The problem is, that whenever I push a new page with such a widget, it uses a weird animation that I want to disable. I found this: [Disable Scaffold FAB animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941252/disable-scaffold-fab-animation/53980090), so I extended FloatingActionButtonAnimator and tried what was shown in the aforementioned example, but unfortunately, it didn't help. I dealt with the offset easily. but the rotation and scale animation persist. Even tweaking the begin and end values of the Tween object doesn't help.

This is the setup in the Scaffold:

```
    floatingActionButton: ActionControls(),
    floatingActionButtonLocation:
        FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButtonAnimator: NoScalingAnimation(),
```

Those are the ActionControls, that are basically my floating buttons:

```
class ActionControls extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _iconButton({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required IconData icon,
    @required Function function,
    Color color,
  }) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: color == null ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : color,
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          icon,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: function,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        _iconButton(
          context: context,
          icon: Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
          function: () {},
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        _iconButton(
          context: context,
          icon: Icons.add,
          function: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my FloatingActionButtonAnimator:

```
class NoScalingAnimation extends FloatingActionButtonAnimator {
  @override
  Offset getOffset({Offset begin, Offset end, double progress}) {
    return end;
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getRotationAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent);
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getScaleAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent);
  }
}
```

Problematic animation example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf0OS.jpg

Comment: Can you add some code example?

Comment: @Sebastian Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FloatingActionButton has a parameter herotag, if you do not define it it will use a defaultHeroTag, when pushing to a new page it checks herotags with same name and applies the animation.

```
FloatingActionButton(
  heroTag: "MyFirstPage", //give it a custom name to avoid same heroTag in each page
  ...
 )
```

UPDATE

```
class First extends StatelessWidget{
  
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('First'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Second(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ActionControls(),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: NoScalingAnimation(),
    );
  }
}

class Second extends StatelessWidget{
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: Text('My Second Page')),
      floatingActionButton: ActionControls(),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: NoScalingAnimation(),
      /*
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => print('tapped')
      ),
      */
    );
  }
}

class ActionControls extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _iconButton({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required IconData icon,
    @required Function function,
    Color color,
  }) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: color == null ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : color,
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          icon,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: function,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        _iconButton(
          context: context,
          icon: Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
          function: () {},
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        _iconButton(
          context: context,
          icon: Icons.add,
          function: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NoScalingAnimation extends FloatingActionButtonAnimator {
  @override
  Offset getOffset({Offset begin, Offset end, double progress}) {
    return end;
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getRotationAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent);
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getScaleAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent);
  }
}
```

I made a minimal reproducible code sample and I didn't find any animation between the first and second page, even changing in the second page the position to FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat or actually inserting a FloatingActionButton(). The only animation I see is from the MaterialPageRoute  fade from below animation

Comment: I am not using an actual FloatingActionButton, but other custom widgets, so  there is no a heroTag field.

Comment: Weird, your example works perfectly, but my project is the same and causes issues. I will try to debug this again. I also added a video example of the animation. Thanks for the help, anyway!

Comment: Ok, I started rebuilding the page from scratch and for now everything is good. I will treat this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the suggested solution was not working in my case. Therefore, I wanted to share the solution that worked for me. Basically I had to use a custom `Animatable` implementation instead of a `Tween`. Here is the implementation of the animator I used:

```dart
class Animator extends FloatingActionButtonAnimator {
  @override
  Offset getOffset({Offset begin, Offset end, double progress}) {
    return end;
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getRotationAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return const _NoAnimation().animate(parent);
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getScaleAnimation({Animation<double> parent}) {
    return const _NoAnimation().animate(parent);
  }
}
```

And I had to use this implementation instead of the Tween:

```dart
class _NoAnimation extends Animatable<double> {
  const _NoAnimation();

  @override
  double transform(double t) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```