# Flutter, remove FAB scaling animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

When page is loaded at first, FAB always do scaling animation stuff by default.

How to remove/disable Floating Action Button scaling animation

what I have done already is

```
return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: AnimationNoScaling(),

...


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimationNoScaling extends FloatingActionButtonAnimator{
  double? _x;
  double? _y;
  @override
  Offset getOffset({Offset? begin, Offset? end, double? progress}) {
    _x = begin!.dx +(end!.dx - begin.dx)*progress!;
    _y = begin.dy +(end.dy - begin.dy)*progress;
    return Offset(_x!,_y!);
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getRotationAnimation({Animation<double>? parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent!);
  }

  @override
  Animation<double> getScaleAnimation({Animation<double>? parent}) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(parent!);
  }
}
```

and this is not working the above code is also refered from other question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Scaffold FAB animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941252/disable-scaffold-fab-animation)

Comment: @AdityaDees If you look at the code, you will notice the OP actually used the code from that answer.

Comment: I think  need add more detail, about version of dart and flutter

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when a page is first loaded, the FAB does not animate. But if you remove the FAB (by setting: `floatingActionButton: null`) and/or bring it back, it animates. If your business logic permits, maybe use `Offstage` or `Visibility` widget, to "hide" the FAB instead of removing it. This way, it will disappear and appear instantly.

Another possible solution is, you don't *have to* use FAB widget, you can pass any widget to `floatingActionButton` property, like an `IconButton` or whatever, so really, anything is possible. :D

Comment: It seems that there are prerequisites. There is no animation when loading with the tab bar as the first page. However, if you go to another tab index and then go back to that page, an animation occurs. And I put Container as an argument value instead of FAB. The result was the same.